# Django DM model constraint: uniqueConstraint or checkConstraint?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to define a unique constraint for my DB model. I have 3 constraints and have no trouble with 2. But the 3rd one is doing my head a little.

So the model class is fairly simply; its a social media connection request model (between user accounts). These are the constraints I am trying to enforce:

1. User1 should have only one connection request to User2: UniqueConstraint works fine.
2. User1 should not be able to send a connection request to User1 (ie self): CheckConstraint works fine.
3. If User1 sends a connection request to User2, then User2 should not be able to send a connection request back to User1: this is the one I am struggling with.

How can I enforce the 3rd constraint here? I initially thought the 1st one enforces the reverse constraint actually (where the uniqueness of the 2 entries in the table are enforced regardless of the order) but it doesnt seem it like (and makes sense too).

```
class ConnectionRequest(models.Model):

    senderAccount = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, related_name='sender_Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipientAccount = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, related_name='recipient_Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requested = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.senderAccount.id) + ' to ' + str(self.recipientAccount.id)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            # duplicate connection request constraint
            models.UniqueConstraint(name='duplicate_connreq_constraint',
                                    fields=['senderAccount', 'recipientAccount']),

            # self connection request constraint
            models.CheckConstraint(name='self_connection_request_constraint',
                                   check=~models.Q(
                                       senderAccount=models.F("recipientAccount")),
                                   ),
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), you could make a functional unique constraint with the [**`Least`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#least) and [**`Greatest`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest) of the two, so:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Least, Greatest


class ConnectionRequest(models.Model):
    senderAccount = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, related_name='sender_Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    recipientAccount = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, related_name='recipient_Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    requested = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.senderAccount_id}  to {self.recipientAccount_id}'

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                name='duplicate_connreq_constraint',
                fields=['senderAccount', 'recipientAccount'],
            ),
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name='self_connection_request_constraint',
                check=~models.Q(senderAccount=models.F("recipientAccount")),
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                Least('senderAccount', 'recipientAccount'),
                Greatest('senderAccount', 'recipientAccount'),
                name='antisymmetric',
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks Willem! It does work like a charm - although I now need to read the documentation to really understand these new keywords.